# Value is concatenated instead of added

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable in which I want to add another seven variables but the variables are concatenated instead of added.

I might have a few mistakes and maybe I over-complicated things.

Tried with unary `+` but it didn't work...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('inputButton').onclick = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputRecomandate');
    var header = document.getElementById('headerA');
    header.innerHTML = input.value * 7;
    document.getElementById('dormiteButton').onclick = function() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById('inputDormite1');
      var input2 = document.getElementById('inputDormite2');
      var input3 = document.getElementById('inputDormite3')
      var input4 = document.getElementById('inputDormite4')
      var input5 = document.getElementById('inputDormite5')
      var input6 = document.getElementById('inputDormite6')
      var input7 = document.getElementById('inputDormite7')
      var oreTotale = document.getElementById('total');
      oreTotale.innerHTML = input1.value + input2.value + input3.value +
        input4.value + input5.value + input6.value + input7.value;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Adauga aici nr de ore de somn pe zi recomandate de tine</h1>
<input id="inputRecomandate" type="text">
<button id="inputButton">Apasa aici</button>
<p> Nr de ore de somn recomandate pe saptamana <span id="headerA">0</span>
</p>
<input id="inputDormite1" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
<input id="inputDormite2" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite marti.">
<input id="inputDormite3" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite miercuri.">
<input id="inputDormite4" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite joi.">
<input id="inputDormite5" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite vineri.">
<input id="inputDormite6" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite sambata.">
<input id="inputDormite7" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite duminica.">
<button id="dormiteButton">Aduna</button>
<p id="total">gsga</p>
```

Comment: If the values are if integer type you have to type cast it before adding. Or else string addition will happen. parseInt()

Comment: Tried parseInt(input1.value + input2.value+...) and it still concatenates them...I am doing something wronk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the 2nd `onclick` `function` is *inside* the 1st one!
I don't think that you intended to do it this way…

After that correction, it seems to be working correctly with some unary `+` on the `input.value`s:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('inputButton').onclick = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputRecomandate');
    var header = document.getElementById('headerA');
    header.innerHTML = +input.value * 7;
  }
  document.getElementById('dormiteButton').onclick = function() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('inputDormite1');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('inputDormite2');
    var input3 = document.getElementById('inputDormite3');
    var input4 = document.getElementById('inputDormite4');
    var input5 = document.getElementById('inputDormite5');
    var input6 = document.getElementById('inputDormite6');
    var input7 = document.getElementById('inputDormite7');
    var oreTotale = document.getElementById('total');
    oreTotale.innerHTML = +input1.value + +input2.value + +input3.value +
      +input4.value + +input5.value + +input6.value + +input7.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Adauga aici nr de ore de somn pe zi recomandate de tine</h1>
  <input id="inputRecomandate" type="text">
  <button id="inputButton">Apasa aici</button>
  <p> Nr de ore de somn recomandate pe saptamana <span id="headerA">0</span>
  </p>
  <input id="inputDormite1" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
  <input id="inputDormite2" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite marti.">
  <input id="inputDormite3" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite miercuri.">
  <input id="inputDormite4" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite joi.">
  <input id="inputDormite5" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite vineri.">
  <input id="inputDormite6" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite sambata.">
  <input id="inputDormite7" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite duminica.">
  <button id="dormiteButton">Aduna</button>
  <p id="total">…</p>

</body>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

Anyway, I propose you that few modifications to simplify your functions:

- Remove the `id`s and add a `class="dormite"` on your 7 inputs,
- Use `querySelectorAll` and `.forEach(…)` to loop through the elements and create the total.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('inputRecomandate');
var header = document.getElementById('headerA');
document.getElementById('inputButton').onclick = function() {
  header.innerHTML = +input.value * 7;
  compare(); // Added this function after comment
}

var oreTotale = document.getElementById('total');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.dormite');
document.getElementById('dormiteButton').onclick = function() {
  var total = 0;
  inputs.forEach(function(elm, index) {
    total += +elm.value;
  })
  oreTotale.innerHTML = total;
  compare(); // Added this function after comment
}

// Added this function after comment:
function compare() {
  console.clear();
  if (+oreTotale.innerHTML > +header.innerHTML)
    console.log("oreTotale > header");
  if (+oreTotale.innerHTML < +header.innerHTML)
    console.log("oreTotale < header");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Adauga aici nr de ore de somn pe zi recomandate de tine</h1>
  <input id="inputRecomandate" type="text">
  <button id="inputButton">Apasa aici</button>
  <p> Nr de ore de somn recomandate pe saptamana <span id="headerA">0</span>
  </p>
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite marti.">
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite miercuri.">
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite joi.">
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite vineri.">
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite sambata.">
  <input class="dormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite duminica.">
  <button id="dormiteButton">Aduna</button>
  <p id="total">…</p>

</body>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your reply is very helpful thank you! I was wondering why I can add the numbers only after I tap on the first button hehe . I have to do my reading about .forEach() . this is totally new for me....when I will understand exactly I will try your method on my own.. Again thank you

Comment: @clauu I knew you couldn't have actually wanted that behaviour! :) I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Quick question...now I want to add some "if's"  let's say i want to print a random message in the console or get an alert if my variable 'oreTotale' is smaller than my variable 'header' . I actually want to compare the values from the 2 variables and print a message...hope you will understand what I mean heh

Comment: I tried something similar on my current code but it says that my variable is not defined https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ERgeNO

Comment: @clau See how I defined the `var` in my snippet above. Outside the functions, so that they can be accessed from all the functions. That is the problem. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172688/discussion-between-clauu-and-takit-isy).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
oreTotale.innerHTML = input1.value*1 + input2.value*1 +  input3.value*1 + 
input4.value*1 + input5.value*1 + input6.value*1 + input7.value*1;
```

input1.value returns a string, convert it to number by mul;tiplying it with 1

Answer (score 1):

**Inputs** are getting concatenated because `.value` returns a `string`. And strings are concatenated on perform addition (+). You will need to convert them to `number`. There are many ways to do that. Listing few of them below

- +input1.value
- Number(input1.value)
- parseFloat(input1.value)
- parseInt(input1.value) // only integers

You can try following with one of them as below

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('inputButton').onclick = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputRecomandate');
    var header = document.getElementById('headerA');
    header.innerHTML = input.value * 7;
    document.getElementById('dormiteButton').onclick = function() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById('inputDormite1');
      var input2 = document.getElementById('inputDormite2');
      var input3 = document.getElementById('inputDormite3')
      var input4 = document.getElementById('inputDormite4')
      var input5 = document.getElementById('inputDormite5')
      var input6 = document.getElementById('inputDormite6')
      var input7 = document.getElementById('inputDormite7')
      var oreTotale = document.getElementById('total');
      oreTotale.innerHTML = +input1.value + +input2.value + +input3.value +
        +input4.value + +input5.value + +input6.value + +input7.value;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Adauga aici nr de ore de somn pe zi recomandate de tine</h1>
<input id="inputRecomandate" type="text">
<button id="inputButton">Apasa aici</button>
<p> Nr de ore de somn recomandate pe saptamana <span id="headerA">0</span>
</p>
<input id="inputDormite1" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
<input id="inputDormite2" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite marti.">
<input id="inputDormite3" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite miercuri.">
<input id="inputDormite4" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite joi.">
<input id="inputDormite5" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite vineri.">
<input id="inputDormite6" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite sambata.">
<input id="inputDormite7" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite duminica.">
<button id="dormiteButton">Aduna</button>
<p id="total">gsga</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and elegant way of achieving the desired result using some of the methods the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object has.

Here are the steps to achieving it:

1. instead of having a unique id for each `input` element use the class name `inputDormite`. For example:

   ```
   <input class="inputDormite" value="1" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
   ```

   Instead of :

   ```
   <input id="inputDormite1" value="1" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
   ```

   This way we can later select all of them with `querySelectorAll`.

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('.inputDormite')
   ```
2. use the [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to convert the selection to an `Array`:

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('.inputDormite')]
   ```
3. first we will map this array to an array of all the values contained in the input element. Use the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to do that. It takes in parameter a callback function and applies it to each element of the array to constitute a new array.

   ```
   Array.map(input => parseInt(input.value) || 0)
   ```

   above we have converted each input element into an int of the string value it contains. `|| 0` allows to set the value to `0` if it doesn't contain any number (it's like a default value)
4. next we will apply the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on the modified array which will allow us to very easily sum all of the values:

   ```
   Array.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value)
   ```

---

The complete code is:

```js
document.querySelector('#inputButton').onclick = function() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#inputRecomandate')
  const header = document.querySelector('#headerA')

  header.innerHTML = input.value * 7;

  document.querySelector('#dormiteButton').onclick = function() {

    document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('.inputDormite')]
      .map(input => parseInt(input.value) || 0)
      .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value)

  }

}
```

```js
document.querySelector('#inputButton').onclick = function() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#inputRecomandate')
  const header = document.querySelector('#headerA')

  header.innerHTML = input.value * 7;

  document.querySelector('#dormiteButton').onclick = function() {

    document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('.inputDormite')]
      .map(input => parseInt(input.value) || 0)
      .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value)

  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Adauga aici nr de ore de somn pe zi recomandate de tine</h1>
<input id="inputRecomandate" value="1" type="text">
<button id="inputButton">Apasa aici</button>
<p> Nr de ore de somn recomandate pe saptamana <span id="headerA">0</span>
</p>

<input class="inputDormite" value="1" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite luni.">
<input class="inputDormite" value="2" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite marti.">
<input class="inputDormite" value="3" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite miercuri.">
<input class="inputDormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite joi.">
<input class="inputDormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite vineri.">
<input class="inputDormite" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite sambata.">
<input class="inputDormite" value="6" type="text" placeholder="Ore dormite duminica.">

<button id="dormiteButton">Aduna</button>
<p id="total"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If inputs are of integer type do type casting

```
oreTotale.innerHTML = parseInt(input1.value) + parseInt(input2.value) +  parseInt(input3.value) + 
parseInt(input4.value) + parseInt(input5.value) + parseInt(input6.value) + parseInt(input7.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, values obtained from input field are of the type string, not numbers. Therefore, you must use `Number()` function to convert the string input values to integer. Modify your code as follows:

```
var input1 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite1'));
var input2 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite2'));
var input3 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite3'));
var input4 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite4'));
var input5 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite5'));
var input6 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite6'));
var input7 = Number(document.getElementById('inputDormite7'));
```